# Pyspark Data cleaning - Identify repeating column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning

I have a pyspark dataframe of the given format.

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | Column_ID_1 | Column_txt_1 | Column_ID_2 | Column_txt_2 | Column_ID_3 | Column_txt_3 | Column_ID_4 | Column_txt_4 | Column_ID_5 | Column_txt_5 | Column_ID_6 | Column_txt_6 | Column_ID_7 | Column_txt_7 |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 |         100 | abc          |       10025 | lkegls       |       64651 | wlejgnlwnr   |       65132 | wejgnn       |       65132 | wejgnn       |       65132 | wejgnn       |       65132 | wejgnn       |
|  2 |        1001 | def          |      648613 | esglknsl     |     3213213 | weklgnlkwn   |       51741 | oiqjerml     |  6565468165 | welkmlwe     |  6565468165 | welkmlwe     |  6565468165 | welkmlwe     |
|  3 |        1002 | hijlkefn     |        5654 | lengl        |      513220 | wlegnlw      |      513220 | wlegnlw      |      513220 | wlegnlw      |      513220 | wlegnlw      |      513220 | wlegnlw      |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the column values for ID 1 are repeating after Column_ID_4, Column_txt_4. Similarly for ID 2 the values after Column_ID_5, Column_txt_5 are repeating.

I want to identify the repeating column name and insert that as a separate column at the end.

The result would look something like this.

```
+----+------------------+----------------------+
| ID | Repeating_Column | Repeating Column_txt |
+----+------------------+----------------------+
|  1 | Column_ID_4      | wejgnn               |
|  2 | Column_ID_5      | welkmlwe             |
|  3 | Column_ID_3      | wlegnlw              |
+----+------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Please don't use images, provide your data as reproducible **text**

Comment: I updated it to reproducible text

Answer (score 0):

I think combination of **explode** and **pivot** function can help you.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
# Define the list of repeating column prefixes
repeating_column_prefixes = ['Column_ID', 'Column_txt']

# Create a list to hold the expressions for the explode function
exprs = []

# Iterate over the repeating column prefixes and create expressions
for prefix in repeating_column_prefixes:
    exprs.append(explode(
        # Use a list comprehension to select the columns with the current prefix
        [col(column) for column in df.columns if column.startswith(prefix)]
    ).alias(prefix))

# Explode the repeating columns
exploded_df = df.select(['ID'] + exprs)

# Pivot the data to get the desired result
result = exploded_df.groupBy('ID').pivot("Column_ID", repeating_column_prefixes[0]) \
    .agg(exprs[0].cast('string').alias("Repeating_Column")) \
    .join(
        exploded_df.groupBy('ID').pivot("Column_txt", repeating_column_prefixes[1])
            .agg(exprs[1].cast('string').alias("Repeating_Column_txt")),
        'ID'
    )

result.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

you could create arrays with the column values and check the distinct of the arrays.

here's an example

```py
# given the input
# +---+----+----+----+----+
# | id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
# +---+----+----+----+----+
# |  1| foo| bar| baz| baz|
# |  2| foo| bar| bar| bar|
# |  3| foo| bar| baz| zap|
# +---+----+----+----+----+

# identify the columns to check
cols = [k for k in data_sdf.columns if k.startswith('col')]
# ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

# create case when statements for array size
check_whens_arr = [func.when(func.size(func.array_distinct(func.array(*cols[i:len(cols)]))) == 1, func.lit(cols[i])) for i in range(len(cols)-1)]

# [Column<'CASE WHEN (size(array_distinct(array(col1, col2, col3, col4))) = 1) THEN col1 END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (size(array_distinct(array(col2, col3, col4))) = 1) THEN col2 END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (size(array_distinct(array(col3, col4))) = 1) THEN col3 END'>]

# pass the variable to a `coalesce`
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('rept_cols', func.coalesce(*check_whens_arr)). \
    show()

# +---+----+----+----+----+---------+
# | id|col1|col2|col3|col4|rept_cols|
# +---+----+----+----+----+---------+
# |  1| foo| bar| baz| baz|     col3|
# |  2| foo| bar| bar| bar|     col2|
# |  3| foo| bar| baz| zap|     null|
# +---+----+----+----+----+---------+
```

---

it is essentially checking if `col1` to `col4` has the same values, then if `col2` to `col4` has same values, and so on. if the values are same, it will result in the name of the first column in the array that has all values same.